# What is the probability of a thief's being caught?

Tags: statistics

If the probability of a thief's being caught in any robbery is 0.20, then what is the probability that he will be caught for the first time in his fourth robbery?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  The idea is that you show us some of your work, or at least your thoughts, so we can help you with specific parts of the problem you are struggling with. So ... what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the robberies are independent (sadly for robbers this is not the case)

you want the following:

$P\left({\text{robbery $1$ is successful},\text{ robbery $2$ is successful},\text{ robbery $3$ is successful},\text{ but robbery $4$ is not successful}}\right)$

Since the robberies are independent this is:

$P(\text{robbery $1$ is successful })\times P(\text{robbery $2$ is successful })\times P(\text{robbery $3$ is successful })\times P(\text{robbery $4$ is not successful })$

Which is equal to:

$0.8^3 \times 0.2$